# IOException when running Play Application with Jenkins

Tags: scala, playframework, jenkins, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to set up Jenkins to run my Play application written in Scala. I am using sbt plugin to build the project. I was following the cloudbees tutorial: http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Playframework. Unfortunately, I am still getting java.io.IOException: Permission denied error and I cant find a solution :(. At first build jenkins was loading all jars from repository:

```
   Checking out Revision 84c8c2c34716cb58ad6661ef12a7c4c03bf43500 (origin/master)
[play-test] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Dhttp.port=80 -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar /opt/sbt/sbt-launch.jar clean compile test
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.0 ...
downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.0/jars/sbt.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.0!sbt.jar (629ms)
...
downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/apply-macro/0.13.0/jars/apply-macro.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.0!apply-macro.jar (750ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    43 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (12440kB/92ms)
Getting Scala 2.10.2 (for sbt)...
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.2!scala-compiler.jar (86664ms)
...
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.4/jansi-1.4.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4!jansi.jar (296ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24390kB/159ms)
[error] java.io.IOException: Permission denied
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? Build step 'Build using sbt' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build using sbt' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

From the second time it crushed right after the start with the message:

```
[play-test] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Dhttp.port=80 -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar /opt/sbt/sbt-launch.jar clean compile test
[error] java.io.IOException: Permission denied
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? Build step 'Build using sbt' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build using sbt' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried a number of solutions, but none of them worked :(. Please help!

Comment: Smells like a permissions issue. Check that your Jenkins user is able to write to the local Play repo.

Comment: Thats what I thought. I added all rights for play-2.2.2 and play-2.2.2/repository. It didnt help.

Comment: Check out permissions for `~/.sbt` and `~/.ivy2`. Start with a simple job in Jenkins that will execute `sbt about`. What you're seeing is to get `sbt` itself up as sbt-launcher can't pull its dependencies down.

Comment: After long fight I started clean jenkins installation and the problem went away. Finally I resigned from using Jenkins (due to problem with compilation - the machine sucks) and created a Python script to compile it locally and deploy automatically after every push. Here it is: [play2-git-auto-deploy](https://github.com/mupakoz/play2-git-auto-deploy)